# How to invoke Mobile First server (adapter) from .net

Tags: .net, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters

I am trying to implement event based push notification using native android.

How do my .net application send notification to mobile first server/adapter  saying a new task has been added.

On the documentation  it says "Notifications can be either pulled from, or pushed by, the back-end system. In this example, a submitNotifications() adapter function is invoked by a back-end system as an external API to send notifications."

There is no clear explanation on how to call this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How can't teach you how to code in .net.

In the push notifications sample application there is also a demo backend. The source code for it is provided in Java. In the source there is invocation of the push adapter.

The end result code-wise is a line such as: `HttpWorker.callAdapter(userId, notificationText, serverUrl);`

You supply to whom the push is supposed to, the text and the MFP server URL.
The Java code opens a connect and sends the message, etc...

The implementation depends on you - more complex, less complex.
[Possible MobileFirst push notification architectures](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/admin/c_push_notification_possible_architectures.html?lang=en)

Comment: I know how to code in .net.. I am trying to understand would there be any dll's that needs to be added to call adapter. Would you please send me the link of java source code for demo backend, i should be able to figure it out from there.

Comment: It's a web-service (well, actually an RPC) call over HTTP so no DLLs are needed - you just need to assemble an HTTP request as shown in the sample, downloaded from here: https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-6-3/notifications/push-notifications-hybrid-applications/